# Finding a cell in row, then using that cell reference to find vertical cell within range of cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Sort of new to Excel, so not sure if this is possible.

In Sheet 1 I have the fixtures of teams playing in matchday 1;

```
A          B   C   D   E
----------------------------
Matchday 1
Team 1         -      Team 4
Team 2         -      Team 5
Team 3         -      Team 6
```

In Sheet 2 I have the previous years fixtures

```
A          B       C          D          E       F
----------------------------------------------------------
Team 1                        Team 2
Home Team  Result  Away Team  Home Team  Result  Away Team
Team 1      1-0    Team 2     Team 2      0-1    Team 1
Team 1      1-1    Team 3     Team 2      2-1    Team 3
Team 1      1-2    Team 4     Team 2      0-1    Team 4
Team 1      2-2    Team 5     Team 2      1-1    Team 5
Team 1      1-0    Team 6     Team 2      3-1    Team 6
```

I want to be able to get the home teams name in Sheet 1, find that teams name in row 2 in Sheet 2, then finding the result based upon who the away team is.

For example, In Sheet 1, I want to find the result of Team 2 at home and Team 5 away from Sheet 2. So finding Team 2 in D1, then finding the result in E6.

Comment: @QHarr No, that will only happen once per Sheet, though they will be in different rows on each sheet

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, that was the issue I was having, the data is imported from an HTML file so is a lot of work to restructure as there are 50 sheets, are is more than just 6 teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in Sheet1!B2 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Sheet2!A:Z, 0, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0)+1), MATCH(C2, INDEX(Sheet2!A:Z, 0, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0)+2), 0))
```

[Linked sample google-spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uecRJiZFBh9k6RjVPQ8Y4gGoGo3-xUjcmiX8VHN96Og/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Thank you for the example too, really helped my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

@Jeeped provides a clear solution to the problem as presented. Frankly, I wasn't aware you could return the `INDEX()` array parameter to be used by an `Index()` as the first "target array". Nifty trick. Thanks @jeeped.

Just an alternative to consider mcclosa:

@Qhar As you say your downloading from HTML, 50 sheets and more than 6 teams is 'a lot of work'.  There is a very helpful MS-Excel add-in for just this type of task: Power Query -- it's a free add-in from Microsoft for 2010 & 2013, and built-in to 2016. Power Query should allow you to automate the task of building the data set, especially from an html source.  It's similar to scripting, but in some respects quite a bit easier. Once the basic 'script' is saved, it can be reused to update/append/sort/transform new data, and build it into a 'normalized' data set' eg:

[image]

And since your not jumping over colums to find "that team's" results, your function call becomes easier, too:
[image]

```
={INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$12,MATCH(A4&E4,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$12&Sheet2!$C$2:$C$12,0))}
```

Note this differs from @jeeped in one important way: it is an array function. You cannot type the curly braces `{}` when entering the function. After the function is typed (copy/pasted), press ctrl+shft+enter.  (If you've already pressed enter, edit the cell , then ctrl+shft+enter.) Once entered, though, it can be copied and pasted like any other cell.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too as I was curious about the add-on, that will actually help with another project!